# fputcsv adds double quotes to multi word columns

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I have a csv line like so:

```
title, short desc, long desc, sku 1233, qty 100, 33.99, http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/images_blogs/wiredscience/2011/06/siau_island_tarsier.jpg,
```

and after `fputcsv` it becomes:

```
title," short desc"," long desc"," sku 1233"," qty 100"," 33.99"," http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/images_blogs/wiredscience/2011/06/siau_island_tarsier.jpg",
```

The code that uses `fputcsv` is:

```
while ( ($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false )
                {
                    fputcsv($result, $fileop); 
                }
```

any way to get rid of the double quotes for mutiple words?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it to work with `fputcsv` so I ended up using `fputs`:

```
fputs($result, implode($fileop, ',')."\n");
```